# Using [Authorize] on the GET and POST methods with same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute, authorize

Maybe the answer to the following is simple, but I have hard time finding the answer:

When I have a GET method in a controller that is secured with the `[Authorize]` attribute, and a POST method (defined with `[HttpPost]`), will the same restrictions apply to it as well? Both methods have the same name, but differ in parameters.

Example code:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
 public ActionResult Delete()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
 {            
     /* the method's logic omitted */
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

Comment: Authorize applies to individual methods, or full classes.  It does not apply to similar methods with the same name with a different signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the controller considers these two separate actions (since that's what they are), and as such, don't share restrictions.